# Recording audio loopback

Tags: python, audio, audio-recording

I'm working on a project that requires usage of my computer's audio. For example, if I'm playing a song in the background I want to be able to record the sound 'on-the-go' and analyze it. I haven't chosen which module I'll be using.

I can't figure out a way to do it, I tried using the Sound Mixer but without any success

Comment: Audio subsystems vary widely depending on the platform. What platform are you targeting?

Comment: @spectras My target platform is Windows if the version matters, Windows 10.

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295920/loopback-what-u-hear-recording-in-python-using-pyaudio