# How to capture system audio input with Python?

Tags: python

My end goal is to create a music visualizer, however the resources I have found online use the microphone or audio files as audio input. However I would like for the audio input be any audio from the system. Such as audio from youtube or audio from a game etc.

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: im running windows

Comment: For Windows, these two Q&A's may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295920/loopback-what-u-hear-recording-in-python-using-pyaudio and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573556/record-speakers-output-with-pyaudio

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, those are not "audio inputs".  Those are "audio outputs".  There is no built-in way to capture what's being sent to the speakers.  If you are using Linux, it's possible to use "loopback recording" to capture what's going to the speakers.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/record_system_sound

If you're running Windows, it's harder.

Comment: I see, I am running windows.