# Read from audio output in PyAudio through loopbacks

Tags: python, pyaudio, loopback, portaudio, pulseaudio

I'm writing a program that records from my speaker output using `pyaudio`. I am on a Raspberry Pi. I built the program while using the audio jack to play audio through some speakers, but recently have switched to using the speakers in my monitor, through HDMI. Suddenly, the program records silence.

```
from pyaudio import PyAudio


p = PyAudio()

print(p.get_default_input_device_info()['index'], '\n')
print(*[p.get_device_info_by_index(i) for i in range(p.get_device_count())], sep='\n\n')
```

The above code outputs first the index of the default input device of `pyaudio`, then the available devices. See the results below.

**Case A:**

```
2

{'index': 0, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'bcm2835 Headphones: - (hw:2,0)', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 8, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.0016099773242630386, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}

{'index': 1, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'pulse', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 32, 'maxOutputChannels': 32, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008684807256235827, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008684807256235827, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034807256235827665, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034807256235827665, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}

{'index': 2, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'default', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 32, 'maxOutputChannels': 32, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008684807256235827, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008684807256235827, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034807256235827665, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034807256235827665, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
```

If I then go into to terminal, enter `sudo raspi-config` and change the audio output to the headphone jack, I get an actual recording, not silence, and receive a different output to the above code.

**Case B:**

```
5

{'index': 0, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'vc4-hdmi-0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 (hw:0,0)', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}

{'index': 1, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'bcm2835 Headphones: - (hw:2,0)', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 8, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.0016099773242630386, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}

{'index': 2, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'sysdefault', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 128, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}

{'index': 3, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'hdmi', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}

{'index': 4, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'pulse', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 32, 'maxOutputChannels': 32, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008684807256235827, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008684807256235827, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034807256235827665, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034807256235827665, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}

{'index': 5, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'default', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 32, 'maxOutputChannels': 32, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008684807256235827, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008684807256235827, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034807256235827665, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034807256235827665, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
```

You can see in case B that I now have access to many different devices. I've attempted recording from all three available inputs in case A, and both #0 and #1 fail. #1 also records silence, and #0 returns `OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels`. If you look closely at case A, you'll see that #0 has `['maxInputChannels'] = 0`, so that's why.

I've attempted to create loopback devices that read from the sound output and introduce another input to pass the audio back in. I would then record from that input, as it would have input channels. I've researched on this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295920/loopback-what-u-hear-recording-in-python-using-pyaudio), but the only solution is for Windows.

I have also attempted to create a loopback device using the `pulseaudio` utility `pactl`. This link [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295430/how-do-i-mix-together-a-real-microphone-input-and-a-virtual-microphone-using-pul) demonstrates what I have tried. Upon succesfully creating a loopback, I'm unable to plug into it using `pyaudio`; it doesn't show up in the list of devices.

Does anybody know...

- How to record from a `pulseaudio` loopback using `pyaudio`?
- An alternative way of creating a loopback on Linux?
- An alternative way of using `pyaudio` to solve my problem?

Thanks very much.